# how to give access to client to view the data from a local database

Tags: database

i want to use a local database to develop a java desktop application so that the application will be offline. My client just want to view the data remotely. What is the solution of this problem and what database i should use?
Please suggest me the solution of this problem. How can i give access to my client to view the data from the local database of the java desktop application. The application might not be connected to internet always but when the computer is connected to internet, my client should be able to view them remotely. Moreover, the client is non-technical so i have to provide him with a dashboard or something like that to view the data.

I have google a lot but didn't got a specific answer.

Comment: I'm sorry to say but the whole scenario does not make much sense.

Comment: yeah i know that, but its client's requirement.

Answer (score 0):

If you're developing the application and want to connect to the database that the client can also see then have the database in the remote server like aws, digital ocean or linode.

> Which Database to use

Thats your preference, based on the clients need, You can use NoSQL or SQL and most probably there will be some Database as a service (DBaaS) available. As it will be remote and you can easily connect to the remote service as well your client.

Examples [Mlab](https://mlab.com/) (Mongo)
or can install MySQL or any database in aws, linode or any other remote servers.

Thats the easy way to do it as after development you have to migrate the system to remote servers and at that time you have to migrate everything.

Another way is, when starting up any database just map the default IP to `0.0.0.0:DEFAULT PORT`. After that you can access, connect the database with `YOUR_IP:DEFAULT_PORT`

Comment: But he wants the application to work offline so i have to use a local database in the application.  But he wants to view the data of it when required online.

Comment: Then map the database ip to 0.0.0.0, that way the database will be offline (localhost:PORT) and online (computer_IP:PORT). Given that the system has static ip

Comment: is there any other solution? Because the client don't have a static IP.

Comment: To my knowledge there is none.